# rqt_bag and rosbag not publishing same messages

Tags: ros, rviz, rosbag, rqt, rqt-bag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'd like to visualize a robot performing a specific task. This involves playing a bag file with rqt_bag and visualizing the tf frames in RViz. I load the bag in rqt_bag, publish tf, and set "Play all Messages".

The first problem: Playing the bag file in rqt_bag when setting "Play all Messages" is *really* slow. Much slower than playing the bag with rosbag play. This isn't a huge issue.

The bigger issue: When visualizing the robot description in RViz the robot is "teleporting" around the space. I looked into this, and found that not all of the tf messages are being published, in spite of setting "Play all Messages". When using rosbag play, this problem doesn't occur.

To test this, I subscribed to tf when playing the bag in rqt_bag and rosbag play. I output the messages to two separate files and compare them in Beyond Compare (amazing program FYI). Many messages played in rosbag play don't show up in rqt_bag.

Is there a current workaround for this? My suspicion is that rqt_bag not publishing all of the tf messages, but could there be a different source of the issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231385/rqt_bag-and-rosbag-not-publishing-same-messages/) by [curranw](https://answers.ros.org/users/17736/curranw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 211 on 2016-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This fixed my problem, although it is quite a hack: http://answers.ros.org/question/11477/using-tf-data-from-bag-files/

---

Originally posted by [curranw](https://answers.ros.org/users/17736/curranw/) with karma: 211 on 2016-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1